# Not able to implement sign out for outlook add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm pushing an outlook add-in to microsoft store.

Application gets failed beacause of sign out requirement .

> Your offer requires an external account or service but is missing one
> or more of the required links allowing the user to Sign out.

The add-in uses React / node and Azure SSO as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-sso-office-add-ins-nodejs) :

Actually office-js have `getTokenAccess()` in order to sign-in user.

```
OfficeRuntime.auth
  .getAccessToken({ allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true, forMSGraphAccess: true })
```

My application actually have a `\` page that contains a button "Connect with microsoft"

When user clicks in I call `getTokenAccess()` then I redirect to `\home` page.

I would implement sign out to fit microsoft validation requirement.

I don't found a way to unvalidate user session.

I have used msal library

```
msalInstance= new PublicClientApplication({
auth: {
    clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    redirectUri: 'https://localhost:3000/logout', 
    postLogoutRedirectUri: 'https://localhost:3000/home'
}})
```

I get the popup promt
I disconnect the account.
I get disconnected then I close the window popup.
Nothing  happens , app does not get redirected to `postLogoutRedirectUri` or `redirectUri`

And when I launch the app again and click on "connect" button I don't get login prompt.

The behaviour that I would implement

When I run the app I check if user is connected or not.

If user havn't sign out I show connection page `\` otherwise redirect to `\home` page.

When User sign out I redirect him to `\` page

Answer (score 0):

> When I run the app I check if user is connected or not.

Sounds like you save the access token somewhere to check if a user is connected or not. It is reasonable to have a `sign out` button to clear that token (remove it) when it is pressed.

You may consider using built-in mechanisms of MS Office applications with the `Single Sign-on` feature in your add-in, see [Enable single sign-on (SSO) in an Office Add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins#requirements-and-best-practices) for more information.

Comment: I'm using as I've mentioned  the build it sso which is working . I'm looking for a way to add sign out. If I have understood you. I only need to delete token from browser storage ?
Also I want to know how to make a check if user is connected or not using the office-js library ?

Comment: If you cache/save the token anywhere, you need to remove it when a user clicks the sign out button. Do you save or cache the token somehow? Did you implement any alternative way of signing in rather than SSO?

Comment: As I said I'm using sso with office-js library  method GetAccessToken() then send it to backend  server to  to validate it. I'm not particularly caching it anywhere. I don't know exactly how office.js save token with the built-in way

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - in that case you may need a sign out button to return to the logging page where you could call the `getAccessToken` method anew to refresh the token.

Comment: So It's only redirection button to home page where I button "connect button" ?  there is no disconnection process ?

Comment: The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide anything for that. You just need to retrieve a new token (renew if necessary) each time the user clicks the sign in button.